# Firebase Web Push notification not triggered when window is open

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, web-notifications

1. i am implementing Firebase Web Push notification in Angular 10
2. everything is working fine when tab is not active, but when Tab is active not able to Trigger for new message.
3. firebase version : 8.3.1
4. @angular/fire version : 6.1.4
5. firebasejs version which is included in firebase-messaging-sw.js : 7.5.0
6. [following this demo](https://medium.com/mighty-ghost-hack/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-cc80d9b36f82)

> i dont know where am going wrong, everything is implemented as per working demo

Answer (score 0):

1. downgrade firebase & @angular/fire library
2. @angular/fire : **5.2.3**
3. firebase : **7.6.0**
4. firebase-messaging-se.js

   ```
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js');
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');
   ```

> **after changes in Library version, it's working fine**